# dijit.Editor's cleared after re-append

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I have problem with dijit.Editor. After removing it's DOM from document and re-appending it, it's value is cleared.

The test for this is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaboshi/WTU6H/): 
According to commented alerts in example, the value is being cleared after appending. It is still in memory after removing editor.

I tried to add "reloading" code to `onLoadDeferred`. But it is not called when reappending editor.

I cannot easily call reload on it by myself, because I am re-appending whole form in my app. I don't know anything about form's contents.

Also, I am quite sure that this is  dijit.Editor's issue. I tested reappending javascript generated Iframe ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaboshi/PPtTN/)) and it is working.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your [iframe javascript test](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/zHGVt/) so it writes to iframe document only once and it seems to behave the same way the Dijit Editor does.

I think you will have to set value of the Editor every time you `placeAt` it, but you do not have to do it manually, you can use one of these:

1. [`dojo/aspect`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect):

   ```
   aspect.after(editor, "placeAt", lang.hitch(editor, function() {
       this.set("value", this.get("value"));
   }));
   ```
2. [`dojo/declare`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/_base/declare):

   ```
   var Editor = declare([DijitEditor], {
       placeAt: function() {
           this.inherited(arguments);
           this.set("value", this.get("value"));
       }
   });
   ```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/PXZk5/

Comment: Now I feel dumb. My iframe test was really bad. Thanks for pointing that out and for solutions which are very nice both.